# Как вставить таблицу treeview в сетку grid

Tags: python, tkinter

Не могу понять, как расположить виджеты по окну, если один из них таблица? Как вставить таблицу `treeview` в сетку `grid`?

Мой код:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(root, width=25, font='Times 12', text='Список смежности вершин')
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=['vertex', 'adj_vertices'], height=15, show='headings')
        self.tree.column('vertex', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('adj_vertices', width=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('vertex', text='Вершина')
        self.tree.heading('adj_vertices', text='Смежные ей вершины')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.label2 = tk.Label(root, width=35, font='Times 12', text='Введите вершину (до 3-ёх символов):')
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=30, font='Times 12')
        self.entry1.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Добавить вершину')
        self.button1.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Удалить вершину')
        self.button2.grid(row=5, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.title("Graph representation")
    root.geometry("700x700+400+50")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Но таблица почему-то не отображается...

Comment: Так и делайте через grid: `self.tree.grid(строка, колонка)`

Comment: @insolor, у меня таблица не отображается таким образом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете `Main`, но не размещаете его в окне `root`. `tree` у вас крепится к фрейму `Main`, поэтому его не видно, а остальные объекты - к `root`, поэтому их видно.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        # Было tk.Label(root, ...) (root вместо self)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, width=25, font='Times 12', text='Список смежности вершин')
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=['vertex', 'adj_vertices'], height=15, show='headings')
        self.tree.column('vertex', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('adj_vertices', width=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('vertex', text='Вершина')
        self.tree.heading('adj_vertices', text='Смежные ей вершины')
        self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Было root вместо self:
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, width=35, font='Times 12', text='Введите вершину (до 3-ёх символов):')
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Было root вместо self:
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=30, font='Times 12')
        self.entry1.grid(row=3, column=0)

        # Было root вместо self:
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить вершину')
        self.button1.grid(row=4, column=0)

        # Было root вместо self:
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Удалить вершину')
        self.button2.grid(row=5, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()  # <-- Main - это фрейм, его нужно разместить в окне
    root.title("Graph representation")
    root.geometry("700x700+400+50")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]